# Extracting word which has more than 3 characters in it from an alphanumeric string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose this is the string

```
input = "{('Blue',): 24, ('lej',): 28, ('green',): 19, ('pul',): 36, ('cas',): 23, ('minit',): 46}"
```

By using this regex I get all words(excludes numbers) but how to do a condition that select only words that has more than three characters in it

```
import re
word1 = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", input))
```

Expecting output like this

```
o/p =  "Blue green minit"
```

Any help would be much appreciated on this.
Thanks

Comment: Use `re.findall("[a-zA-Z]{4,}", input)`. `{4,}` limiting quantifier matches 4 or more consecutive occurrences of the quantified pattern.

Comment: That was really easy and nice, but couldn't have achieved it without your help... Thanks a ton

Comment: Oh, that is soooo basic. Just spend 15 minutes at http://regexone.com, you will learn that and much more really quickly.

Comment: ohh thanks for that one......